# How cut a data file that have colums separated by spaces

Tags: bash, scripts, 14.10, awk

I have a data file with 2 columns

```
1.0000    9.9398383
1.4399    8.0000000
2.5688    7.9393838

1.0000    4.0000000
1.4399    9.0094949
2.5688    3.9932323

1.0000    8.9393993
1.4399    7.3838473
1.5688    2.8337738
```

I want to create a different files with this data separates by a blank line, but I dont know how to cut the file after or before the blank line, please help.

Comment: It sounds like you want to *split* (divide horizontally - by rows) rather than *cut* (divide vertically - by columns)

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/^$/{n++} ; {print $0 >> "fnew"n}' dfile
```

Will take the data from dfile, and place the lines into `fnew`, `fnew1`...

```
less dfile
1.0000    9.9398383
1.4399    8.0000000
2.5688    7.9393838

1.0000    4.0000000
1.4399    9.0094949
2.5688    3.9932323

1.0000    8.9393993
1.4399    7.3838473
1.5688    2.8337738

less fnew
1.0000    9.9398383
1.4399    8.0000000
2.5688    7.9393838

less fnew1
1.0000    4.0000000
1.4399    9.0094949
2.5688    3.9932323
```

Comment: ... or `awk -vRS= '{print > "fnew" NR}'`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the code edit - I knew I forgot something.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00 -lanE 'open my $fh, ">", "${ARGV}_$."; say $fh $_; close $fh' file
```

where:

- `-00` uses blank lines as the record separator
- `-lanE` does stuff (mostly, looping over the records in the input)
- `$ARGV` is the current filename
- `$.` is the current record number
- `$_` is the current record

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd probably use Awk for this task myself, another option is `csplit`:

```
csplit file '/^$/' '{*}'
```

will split `file` into pieces delimited by the regular expression pattern `/^$/` repeating as many times as possible `{*}`

By default, the output files will be named `xx00`, `xx01` etc. but you can change both the prefix and suffix format as described in `man csplit`, for example

```
csplit -f 'new' -b '_%d' file '/^$/' '{*}'
```

for names of the form `new_0`, `new_1` etc.

(For fixed length pieces, you might consider using plain `split` rather than the regex-based `csplit`).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe?

cat data_2_cut.txt | cut -d" " -f1 >> first_column_file.txt

cat data_2_cut.txt | cut -d" " -f2 >> second_column_file.txt

Answer (score -1):

Or like this, data is your file with 2 columns; first and second row separated by space.

Save first row to file 1st:

```
awk -F " " '{print $1}' data > 1st
```

Save second row to file 2nd:

```
awk -F " " '{print $2}' data > 2nd
```